# Remove Exceptions from a Series

Tags: vb6, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2007-addin

I have a series in Outlook with a few exceptions.  What I would like to do is remove all exceptions from this series.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?  Since the exceptions list is read-only I have tried clearing the recurrence pattern and re-applying all of the values sans the exceptions list like this:

```
Dim tRType As OlRecurrenceType
Dim tRPSD As Date
Dim tRPED As Date
Dim tST As Date
Dim tET As Date
Dim tOcc As Integer
Dim tInterval As Integer

tRType = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.RecurrenceType
tRPSD = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternStartDate
tRPED = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternEndDate
tST = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.startTime
tET = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.endTime
tOcc = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.Occurrences
tInterval = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.Interval

oAppointmentItem.ClearRecurrencePattern
' This save throws an error. 
'oAppointmentItem.Save

' Make this call to flip to reccurring...
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.RecurrenceType = tRType
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternStartDate = tRPSD
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternEndDate = tRPED
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.startTime = tST
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.endTime = tET
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.Occurrences = tOcc
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.Interval = tInterval
```

Thus far I am having no luck with this approach.  Once calling ClearRecurrencePattern all of the data cannot be updated (or will not persist anyways), which is why I tried the Save but, it does not work. There has to be a better way and I am just missing it.

I've also thought of doing a full copy of the appointment item and then delete/re-add but, I would like to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and will post it here in case anyone needs it.  You can modify the patternendtime (and I am assuming start time) to cause it to clear the exceptions list.  The code below causes all exceptions to be removed from the series.

```
Dim tEndDate As Date
Dim currentEndDate As Date
Dim dateInterval As Double
currentEndDate = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternEndDate
tEndDate = oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternEndDate
' Add a year to the end date so we can force the exceptions to remove.
DateAdd "yyyy", 1, tEndDate
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternEndDate = tEndDate
oAppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern.PatternEndDate = currentEndDate
```